# How to use mpg123.exe in a Python script

Tags: python, mp3, wav

I am trying to use mpg123 in a Python script to convert an .mp3 file to a .wav file. How do I download and use `mpg123.exe`? I am using a mac.

Here is a snippet of the code to see how it's being used:

```
mpg123_command = '..\\mpg123-1.12.3-x86-64\\mpg123.exe -w "%s" -r 10000 -m "%s"' 
out_file = 'temp.wav' 
cmd = mpg123_command % (out_file, mp3_file) 
temp = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the mac osx port: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mosx-mpg123/